# checkbox validation in windows mobile

Tags: windows, mobile, checkbox

In the windows mobile application how i am validate the checkbox.
  for example:

```
        I have two checkboxs A,B

        If i checked the A checkbox, B checkbox is Unchecked and If i checked the B checkbox A checkbox is unchecked  

        I struggling couple of days plz help me  how i am solve it.
```

Thanks
brite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What language are you writing in?

In C#, I would set EventHandlers to watch for `Checkbox1.Checked = True` and set `Checkbox2.Checked = false` (and vice versa)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want a [RadioButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.aspx)?  It does that out of the box.